# lambda function in key argument in sorted() method in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, lambda, counter

I found this code from online and tries to find what is the logic.But i didn't get it.

```
from collections import Counter
arr = [4,3,1,1,3,3,2]
k = 3
c = Counter(arr)
print(c)
s = sorted(arr,key = lambda x:(c[x],x))
print(s)
print(len(set(s[k:])))
```

what the line

```
s = sorted(arr,key = lambda x:(c[x],x))
```

do? what is the use of (c[x],x) in the code. The output given by the code is correct. But i dont know what the lambda function do in this code.

Comment: The function supplied to `key` is applied to each element of `arr` before comparison is performed. In this case, the elements (`x`) are transformed into tuples with an additional first element which is the number of occurances (`c[x]`). Since tuples are compared based on the left elements first (see `(0, 1) < (1, 0)`) then the sorted output will contain values from `arr` arranged by ascending number of occurances. The second element of the tuple being `x` means that, for elements that occur an equal number of times, the secondary sorting will be performed with `<` between the elements directly